# How to setup proxy Credentials using HttpTransportBindingElement on WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I coded a WCF Service using HttpTransportBindingElement in conjunction with IIS on port 80.
The code works fine as long as no proxy is used. But if a customer has a http-proxy the communication between WCF-Client and Server does not work in this case by occuring following error:

*'There was no endpoint listening at ... that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.'*

**It is essential to use settings by code ONLY!**

here is my code approach for that issue but i stuck on it:

```
bool SendClientRequest(Action<ICustomerService> channel)
{

  string proxy ="my.proxy.domain:8080";
  string user = "user1";
  string password="secret";

  // maybe i do not need this 3 lines!
  WebProxy webproxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
  webproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
  WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webproxy;

  CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
  customBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpTransportBindingElement()
  {

   AuthenticationSchemes.None : AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,                
   ProxyAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy) ? null : new Uri(proxy),
   UseDefaultWebProxy = false,
   BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
   TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
   MaxReceivedMessageSize = 84087406592,
   MaxBufferPoolSize = 0x1000000,
   MaxBufferSize = 0x1000000

  });


  using (ChannelFactory<ICustomerService> factory = new  
  ChannelFactory<ICustomerService>(customBinding ))
  {
   IClientChannel contextChannel = null;
   string url = "http://my.domain.de/Distribution/eService.svc", 
   EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(url);
   ICustomerService clientChannel = factory.CreateChannel(ep);                


   contextChannel = clientChannel as IClientChannel;
   contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(rcvTimeout );

   channel(clientChannel); // <- here i get the exception!
   return true;
  }
}
```

I tried several solution approaches but nothing seems to be specific like mine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a few options, some of which I'll detail below.

First you could set `UseDefaultWebProxy` to true. This would then mean that proxy information is retrieved automatically from system proxy settings, configurable in Internet Explorer (Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings > Proxy server). This may be appropriate if you don't need to specify credentials for proxy use.

Another approach that's worked for me is to use the `ProxyAuthenticationScheme` property within your `HttpTransportBindingElement()` object. This property is only available on the `CustomBinding` class and allows an authentication scheme to be specified that will be used to authenticate against a proxy. In conjunction with this, the proxy server must be set against property `ProxyAddress`. Last but not least, the credentials to use against the proxy should be set according to the authentication scheme used, so for example, using `AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm` would mean setting the UserName and Password properties on `ChannelFactory.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential` or perhaps `ChannelFactory.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential`

With the second approach, be sure to note the difference between holding credentials in the ChannelFactory for use with the remote service versus credentials used for the proxy server. I've highlighted these in the code example below for clarity:

```
// Example service call using a CustomBinding that is configured for client
// authentication based on a user name and password sent as part of the message.
var binding = new CustomBinding();

TransportSecurityBindingElement securityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();

var secureTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
secureTransport.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
secureTransport.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://some-proxy");
secureTransport.ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;

binding.Elements.Add(securityBindingElement);
binding.Elements.Add(secureTransport);

var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://some-service");

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpointAddress);

// Credentials for authentication against the remote service
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "serviceUser";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "abc";

// Credentials for authentication against the proxy server
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "domain\user";
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "xyz";

var client = factory.CreateChannel();
client.CallMethod();
```